# Suggestion to consider improving MatFile support by using code from csmatio to read and write .mat files

Tags: ilnumerics

is anyone using MatFile classes in ilnumerics?

I just tried to open a MAT file created using csmatio and found I could not import it into ilnumerics application.

Hit throw new Exception("`element data type is not supported`");

as there is no support for `mxSTRUCT_CLASS` in the method

`private ILBaseArray read_miMATRIX(BinaryReader br).`

Is it a lot of work to add support for mxSTRUCT_CLASS?

Answer (score 0):

ILNumerics will add support for HDF5 soon. This will also provide access to recent Matlab mat files. There are no plans to improve the old ILMatFile interface currently.